# Light on everything is gone directx

Tags: c++, directx

When I turn of light.  I can see my object but with out the 3D light.
I set my object position to this 0, 0, 10.
Here is my code to set up my Light

```
D3DLIGHT9 light;
  ZeroMemory( &light, sizeof(D3DLIGHT9) );
  light.Type       = D3DLIGHT_DIRECTIONAL;
  light.Diffuse.r  = 1.0f;
  light.Diffuse.g  = 1.0f;
  light.Diffuse.b  = 1.0f;
  light.Diffuse.a  = 1.0f;
  light.Range      = 1000.0f;

  // Create a direction for our light - it must be normalized  
  D3DXVECTOR3 vecDir;
  vecDir = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f,10.0f,10);
  D3DXVec3Normalize( (D3DXVECTOR3*)&light.Direction, &vecDir );

  // Tell the device about the light and turn it on
  d3ddev->SetLight( 0, &light );
  d3ddev->LightEnable( 0, TRUE );
```

[image: red thingies are normals]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with setting up the light, maybe your normal vectors are wrong in your 3d geometry.

Comment: Well nothing is wrong with the set up but when i turn on light I can't see my object anymore i know my object getting drawn but the light is not pointing on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't possibly tell you exactly what the problem is without a more complete source listing.  Having said that, I have an idea.

Check the normals on your object.  If your normals are incorrect, turning on lighting might cause the object to render as black, which may make it disappear if your background is black.

Comment: I tried changing background to white.  I can see my object black.  So, it must be the light is not hitting it.

Comment: I didn't know how to check the normals but i used DXviewer to see the normals i posted  screen shot of what i saw

Comment: If you need any code just comment back because i don't know which one you need, i have class for object and directx.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check.  The main this is whether you set D3DRS_LIGHTING to TRUE.

Another thing to check is your material settings.  Set D3DRS_COLORVERTEX to TRUE. Also if you don't have vertex colours you will need to set D3DRS_DIFFUSEMATERIALSOURCE to D3DMSC_MATERIAL and set a material with a call to SetMaterial.

I always found the lighting pipeline infuriating complicated on D3D9.  I HIGHLY recommend just using shaders as Fixed function is not used any more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you rendering out in a shader? If so the fixed function lighting will not work, you'll have to code your own lighting system into the shader you're using to render the model.

Comment: well the "turning the light on" part seems to indicate that that is not the case ... still its probably worth saying ;)